# Wake On Lan ネットワークカードが2枚あるとき

Tags: windows

ご教授よろしくお願いします｡

現在のシステム構成は以下の通りです｡

PC-A …　常時運転しているPC｡マジックパケットを送る側｡ネットワークカード2枚差し windows 2012 r2
PC-B …　必要な時だけ運転させたいPC｡　マジックパケットを受け取る側 windows 8.1

PC-Aにはネットワークカードが2枚刺さっています｡
1枚はインターネットに繋がっており､もう1枚はローカルネットワークに繋がっています｡
PC-BはPC-Aと同じローカルネットワークに繋がっています｡

この場合､PC-AからWOL用のマジックパケットを送ろうとするとインターネットに繋がっているネットワークカードにマジックパケットが飛んでしまい｡PC-Bを起動する事ができません｡

インターネットに接続しているカードを無効にするとローカルネットワーク側にマジックパケットが飛ぶので､希望通りPC-Bの起動はできます｡

本題ですが､上記のような構成の場合､
マジックパケットを送る時に使用するネットワークカードを指定する方法はないでしょうか｡

アプリケーションを作ればいいのですが､時間がなく､良い方法があれば､そちらを採用したいと考えております｡

ちなみにマジックパケットをおくるのはフリーソフトを使っています｡
http://www.vector.co.jp/soft/winnt/util/se508229.html

どうぞ､よろしくお願いします｡

↓↓Fumu7さん　回答後にWireSharkでも確認しました｡
使用LANカードでWOLマジックパケットを送っている事が確認できました｡
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「マジックパケットをおくるのはフリーソフト」のダウンロードに含まれているファイル　"_README_WWOL.txt"に、ブロードキャスト IP アドレスと MAC アドレスを設定する事が書かれていますが、設定はされていますか？

PC-AとPC-BをつないでいるローカルネットワークのブロードキャストIPを指定していれば、ローカルネットワークにブロードキャストされるのではないかと思われるのですが。

ご確認ください。

Comment: Fumu7さん､ありがとうございます｡　ブロードキャストアドレスを以前は255.255.255.255で送っていたのですが､192.168.x.255というように使用するネットワーク内のブロードキャストに変更する事で成功しました｡

余談といいますか､質問なのですが
これはブロードキャストアドレスのネットワーク部を確認して､使用するLANカードを選定しているんでしょうか｡｡
制作者ではないFumu7さんに聞くことではないと思いますが…

パケットを送るLANカードの選定メカニズムがいまいちイメージつきません｡｡

Comment: その選定メカニズムのことをネットワークルーティングといいます。 この質問は解決したんですよね？ならば Fumu 7 さんの回答に解決マークを入れて、ルーティングに関しては別の質問を発行するほうが stackoverflow 的には好まれます。

Comment: 774RRさん､コメントありがとうございます｡　解決マークをつけ､マジックパケットのルーティングについては別の質問を発行します｡