# Wake On Lanの引数にブロードキャストIPアドレスを指定する理由

Tags: network

[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23717/wake-on-lan-%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%8C2%E6%9E%9A%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D)で、NICが複数ある環境でWOLのマジックパケットを送るNICを指定するには、ブロードキャストIPアドレスを指定するといいと聞きました。

マジックパケットの送信には以下のソフトを使っています。
http://www.vector.co.jp/soft/winnt/util/se508229.html

このアプリケーションは引数にMACアドレスとブロードキャストアドレスを指定するのですが､
引数のブロードキャストアドレスからPCに複数あるNICの中からブロードキャストを送るNICをどうやって認識しているのでしょうか｡
以前､違うフリーソフトを使っており､ブロードキャストが255.255.255.255で送っていた時は送りたいNICを判断できない状況でした｡

Comment: unarist様､質問内容の編集ありがとうございます｡

Answer (score 3, accepted):

たぶんIPルーティングの仕組みによるものではないかと思います。

OSがルーティングテーブルをもっていて宛先アドレスと送信インターフェースの組み合わせを管理しています。

コマンドプロンプトで route print を実行すると確認できます。

1. ネットワーク宛先 : 宛先ネットワークのアドレス
2. ネットマスク : 宛先ネットワークのサブネットマスク
3. ゲートウェイ : ゲートウェイのIP
4. インターフェイス : パケットを送出するNICのIP
5. メトリック : 宛先ネットワークへの経路が複数ある場合小さいメトリック値の経路を選択

例えばNICが2つあり、それぞれ次のIP/サブネットマスクだとします。

NIC(1): 192.168.1.10/255.255.255.0
NIC(2): 192.168.2.20/255.255.255.0

IPとサブネットマスクからブロードキャストアドレスはそれぞれ次のようになります。

サブネット(1): 192.168.1.255
サブネット(2): 192.168.2.255

あとはルーティングテーブルからパケットを送信するNICを割り出せます。
この辺の処理をOSがやってくれてます。

(追記)

> 以前､違うフリーソフトを使っており､ブロードキャストが255.255.255.255で送っていた時は送りたいNICを判断できない状況でした｡

憶測ですが ルーティングテーブルで 255.255.255.255 宛てのインターフェースがループバックアドレス (127.0.0.1) になっていると 自分宛てにしか送信されないのでそのせいかもしれません。

Comment: take88様､回答ありがとうございます｡
納得しました｡　ルーティングテーブルからNICを割り出すのはこうやってるのですね｡
大変勉強になりました｡

Comment: take88様､　私の環境では､"自分宛てにか"ではなく､意図しないNIC側にブロードキャストを送っていました｡WireSharkでブロードキャストが確認できず､違うNICに対してパケットキャプチャしたら､そちらでブロードキャストが発生していました｡｡｡　

255.255.255.255に対するインターフェースが複数登録されており､
127.0.0.1のメトリックの数値が一番大きいため､今回は自分宛にならなかったのかなと思います｡

この考え方で､問題ないでしょうか｡

Comment: @Kazuki Saito たぶんその解釈で合ってると思いますよ